# Running a Hadoop Map-Reduce Job

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new with Hadoop and I am trying to run a word count job on a single node cluster that I recently installed on my desktop.  I am following the tutorial below:

http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/hadoop/your-first-hadoop-map-reduce-job/

Currently I am stuck on step 3, and receive an error when I attempt to run:

~/development/Hadoop_projects/word_count$ mvn clean install

The error I get is:

Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

I think i installed maven correctly, but have no idea. I am running this on ubuntu 14.04, any ideas on what to do about the java home path, or is there another issue going on here?

#

The above error was fixed by fixing the JAVA_HOME path, but now I get the following error once I run mvn clean install:

```
hduser@venus:~/development/Hadoop_projects/word_count$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.088s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 14 23:07:21 PDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/hduser/development/Hadoop_projects/word_count). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

I created the pom.xml file in my word_count folder, but for some reason it is not being recognized when I run mvn.  when I `ls word_count` there is no pom.xml in the directory, but I can see it in the Files gui window.

Comment: Your `JAVA_HOME` path is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a terrific [Ask Ubuntu article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-openjdk) which explains in detail how you can set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.  I am applying here the solution I found there, adapted for your particular setup.

Open `/etc/environment` in any editor and add the following line to the file:

```
JAVA_HOME="usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/"
```

Note carefully that I did *not* append `bin/java` to the path, which would be wrong.  From a command prompt type the following to load the new environment variable:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Finally, verify that `JAVA_HOME` be set correctly by typing this in a command prompt:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: I encountered a new error when I fixed the JAVA_HOME path -_-

Comment: What is the error?  You might want to post a new question actually.

Comment: You would need to show us your current POM and the location of this file.

Comment: OK nvm, I saved the POM in the wrong user directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the variable JAVA_HOME is not set correctly for you.
You should check the value of this system variable.
The first course of this tutorial:
http://how-to-program-in-java.com/core-java-tutorial/
explains how to set the java environment including the JAVA_HOME variable.
The java home is set in the same way for both java and Hadoop.